# Loop through visible cells only

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that finds new values in another sheet (sh1) and adds them to sheet2 (sh2), however, before this happens, the macro filters some specific values ("CONSULTANT I", "PROMOTER I", "PROMOTER II", "SALES PROMOTER I"). I need to consider as new values ONLY the filtered results (visible rows), how can I achieve this?

Follows the code I have -

```
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TabLE1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:= _
        Array("CONSULTANT I", "PROMOTER I", "PROMOTER II", _
        "SALES PROMOTER I"), Operator:=xlFilterValues


   Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STAFF")
   Set Sh1 = Workbooks("MIS25044.xlsb").Sheets(1)

ThisWorkbook.Activate
   Lastrow = Sh2.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

   iRow1 = 2

   'Loop through values in column A of Sheet2
   Do
      Set FindCell = Sh2.Range("a2", Sh2.Cells(Lastrow, "A")).Find(What:=Sh1.Cells(iRow1, "E"), _
             After:=Sh2.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
      If FindCell Is Nothing Then
         'add to bottom of list
         Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
         Sh2.Cells(Lastrow, "A") = Sh1.Cells(iRow1, "E")
      End If
      iRow1 = iRow1 + 1
   Loop Until IsEmpty(Sh1.Cells(iRow1, "E"))
```

Comment: `If Sh1.Rows(iRow1).Visible Then`

Comment: Could not make it work, an error message comes up

Answer (score 0):

`Find()` will already skip any value located on a row which is hidden *using a filter*.

Note this is **not** the case if you've manually hidden the row(s): i.e. values on rows hidden manually can be located using `Find()`

Comment: Can I substitute find() for anything that will not look under hidden values? I could not make YowE3k´s answer work.

Comment: My point was that find() will *already* ignore any rows which are filtered out: you don't need to do anything special to implement that part.